# facebook allow access dialog

Tags: facebook

I've developed a facebook app (type: iframe) that will load within a fan page's tab.  On that tab I have a link (code below) that goes to a page outside of the facebook domain, and it opens in a new window.  My link has the "requirelogin=1" attribute so I can pop up facebook's require access dialog when the user clicks the link.

My problem is after the user clicks "the Allow" button in the "allow access" dialog, my link loads in the same window instead of opening a new one.  Has anyone come across this problem or have a suggestion to get my link to open in a new window after the user clicks the "Allow" button?  One solution I tried was to set my href to an interim page which would call window.open to pop my url and then also reload the fan page tab that I was currently on, but that seems like a really hacky solution.  Any additional ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can force the link that opens the dialog to do so in a new window with `target` :

```
<a href="facebook_dialog_link" target="_blank">Logging with Facebook</a>
```

Hope that helps !